# Technical review: Unable to apply patch InitializeWebsiteDefaultSock

Tags: magento2, patches, marketplace

I have written a simple extension for Magento 2 which I want to publish at the Marketplace.

But I am stuck for months to get it through the technical review process. While the CodeSniffer passes, the 2 other tests fail. This is my error message:

> Unable to apply patch Magento\InventorySales\Setup\Patch\Schema\InitializeWebsiteDefaultSock for module Magento_InventorySales.
> Original exception message: The default website isn't defined. Set the website and try again.

I tested various PHP-Versions in the composer-file, various patches I found on the Internet, and various dependencies. Everything failed. Since this is a black-box I really have no idea.

If somebody has a hint or an idea, please let me know! BTW the source code is free and can be found here: https://gitlab.bounce-experts.com/bounce-experts-plugins/magento-2-bounce-experts-and-recombee-power-pack

I have some newer versions which should work with Magento 2.3. and 2.4 together, but since the error message in the review has never changed, I have not committed it yet.

The changes are related to the `BounceExperts\BMRecombeePowerPack\Block\Widget\RecommendedProducts`
now it's extending `Magento\CatalogWidget\Block\Product\ProductsList` class but this class has changes in the __construct method for 2.3 and 2.4 and the order of dependencies is different which is causing compilation issues on 2.4 so this class is no longer extending ProductsList class.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I think you could try adding the `sequence` node to your `etc/module.xml` file. Because you are adding a new attribute, it needed for the Product to be loaded before your module.

One tip for uploading extensions to MKP, you can always create a ticket for the staff to support you. They answer within a day.

https://marketplacesupport.magento.com/hc/en-us

Comment: I already try adding `sequence` to the `etc/module.xml` but it doesn't help. It throws more errors with dependencies and code sniffer is not validating core magento modules that are included in `sequence` I will submit a ticket to the marketplace support.